# Unexpected keyword argument when providing correct arguments

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new row for my model model_name in Django 1.11.2

My model looks like

```
class model_name(models.Model):
  attribute = models.CharField(
    max_length = 255,
    null = True,
  )
```

Inside my views I am trying to do something like

```
variable = model_name(attribute="String Value")
```

But I am getting an the error 
"model_name() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attribute'"

I have done something similar in the past and had it working but for some reason it isn't now. Any ideas as to why? Any help in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you should do this ```variable = model_name.objects.create(attribute="String Value")```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that as well but it didn't work. I renamed my model and that seemed to solve the issue for me. Have a good one! (: